# bs4 cannot call findchildren due to NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I tried using Beautiful Soup in order to parse some HTML and am having some trouble with the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

results = 20
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.hydroshare.org/search')
element = WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'items-discovered_wrapper')))

innerHTML = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(innerHTML,'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table',{'id':'items-discovered'})
print (type(table)) # Returns <class 'bs4.element.Tag'
children = table.findchildren() # TypeError: 'NoneType' Object is not callable
```

I cannot tell here why printing out type(table) returns a Tag object, but then when I try and run table.findchildren() (or any other function allowed by the Tag object), somehow this table gets converted into null. I have also typed in

```
print(table)
```

which results in a HTML string.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to work around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot tell here why printing out type(table) returns a Tag object

Because `table`s `type` is a BS4 tag.

As for finding the children, the function you want to use is actually `.findChildren()`. You just missed capitalizing the 'C'. So what you really need on that last line is:

`children = table.findChildren()`

EDIT: As @abarnert pointed out, `.findChildren()` is technically depricated in `beautifulsoup4`, however the function still exists. The new way to get the same result would be to use `.find_all()` without specifying any parameter. Both functions work and return the same results. So it would be best to use `children = table.find_all()`

Comment: this worked! I was confused before because I inserted some garbage value for the function and got the same error (i.e. children - table.somegarbagefunction()), but @abarnert provided a good explanation for why I won't get an attribute error here. Thank you both

Comment: `findChildren` is a BS3 method that’s only preserved for making it easier to port legacy code. Don’t recommend it for new code in BS4.

Comment: @abarnert you are correct. I just edited my answer to show the usage of what the function has been replaced with, which is `.find_all()`

Comment: @crookedleaf Those functions haven't actually been deprecated (as in raising `DeprecationWarning`), but IIRC that's explicitly because people keep suggesting them in new answers, and especially on Stack Overflow, so the authors still can't get away with removing them, even years after BS3 was abandoned…

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method as `findchildren`, so trying to call it is an error.

With most Python code, you’d get a clearer `AttributeError` saying that `findchildren` doesn’t exist. But BS4 nodes have that nice shortcut where you can write `node.spam` instead of `node.find('spam')`. So it’s calling `find('findchildren')`, which returns `None`, and then you try to call that `None`.

As for how to fix it… I’m not sure what you’re trying to call here (usually errors like this, someone has copied and pasted some BS3 code that was already deprecated in 3.0 and doesn’t exist in 4.x, but that’s not the case here). So all I can suggest is that you read the docs to find the method you actually need. There are multiple ways to search, iterate, etc. both immediate children and all descendants, and I assume one of them is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code

```
 children = table.findchildren()
```

with

```
children = table.findChildren()
```

It will work fine. 
For Example :;

```
findpsubchild=soup.find('p',class_="story")
all_p_subchild=findpsubchild.findChildren()
print(all_p_subchild)
```